# Canonical Link Does Not Make Anything

Tags: head, canonical-link

Guys I have two different link but same website.

one of them is: https://example.com/

other is: https://www.example.com/

I am doing this process in a nodejs and pug. So I have a layout file which I have added my canonical link in order to effect every page of my website.

My canonical link (in Pug syntax):

```
link(rel="canonical", href="https://www.example.com/")
```

But I have added this link to my `head` in my **layout.pug**

Why it is  not redirecting to canonical url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ["canonical" `link` type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types) does not redirect browsers to a different URL. Its purpose is to tell search engine spiders which variant of a page to index.